# How to set only keyboard language / layout in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, regedit

How do I set only keyboard layout/language in Windows 10?

I wanna be able to change only the keyboard language. But it does also end up changing the Apps & Website.

I tried this.

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList da-DK,en-US -Force
Set-Culture da-DK # Region?
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale da-DK
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language en-US # Changed language in windows
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 61
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/table-of-geographical-locations
```

But the Apps and Websites is changed to da-DK too.

[image]

It seems to follow the priority of the WinUserLanguageList. But that is also the only direct way of setting the keyboard language I have found.

So is there a command to only set the keyboard language?
Or a command to only set the Apps and Websites language?

Comment: Perhaps you mean keyboard **layout** ? In that case [this](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/registry/tree/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Keyboard-Layout/index) might help. You can find the complete table of [Keyboard identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values?view=windows-11#keyboard-identifiers) here. Remember that although these are hex (numeric) values, they need to be written to the registry as **strings**.  Modifying the registry is always risky, so make sure you keep a copy of how things were to be able to restore.

Comment: Yes exactly :)
I if i change the default value in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout
I can change the keyboard layout. 
But I have to do a signout for it to take effect.
Was hoping for something that did change it instantly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution originally at my **[PowerShell keyboard layout gist](https://gist.github.com/pabloaugusto/d36d7d8e7cadc3fd172ff88956243903)**

**NOTE:** This approach was tested with `WIN10` and `WIN11`

### Steps

1. Choose the [Keyboard layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs?view=windows-11) from M$ documentation.
2. Identify Installed languages positions `PS > Get-WinUserLanguageList`
3. Add desired keyboard layout (**if not present yet**) to any installed language
4. Apply settings

```bash
#Add international keyboard layout to first language

$actualKB = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$actualKB[0].InputMethodTips.Add('0409:00020409') #change [0] to your desired lang position
Set-WinUserLanguageList $actualKB -Force

#Set international keyboard as default to current user

Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip "0409:00000409" #set default keyboard en-US(International)
```

### Your Script

Above i've shared how to deal with it generally. Bellow i'll put how to deal with it in your example script ensuring we've en-US international keyboard defined

```bash
Set-WinUserLanguageList da-DK -Force

#How we've set the lang list with only one lang, the lang id is [0]
$actualKB = Get-WinUserLanguageList #get lang list object
$actualKB[0].InputMethodTips.Clear() #OPTIONAL: clear all da-DK keyboard layouts to avoid annoying keyboard layout changes by accidentally shortcut triggers
$actualKB[0].InputMethodTips.Add('0409:00020409') #add en-US (international) KB layout

Set-WinUserLanguageList $actualKB -Force #update lang list with KB Settings
```

NOTE: If You sure en-US international keyboard layout is present, jump last steps and just run following code to set it as default to current user:

```bash
Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip "0409:00000409" #set default keyboard en-US(International)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add another Language in the Time and Language settings, you can press the Windows Key + Space Bar to quickly change your keyboard layout and only the keyboard layout.

This is how the menu looks in German on Windows 11 but Windows 10 should be similar. Just press the colored button to add your language, wait for it to install but don't switch to it / switch back to your usual main language after and then Windows + Space should work.

[Windows 11 Time and Language Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WHYh.png)

This should also add a keyboard layout switcher indicator to your taskbar.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking more for a command or any background job to change it instantly.